# Is this true or false?: $\log(f(n)) = o(\log(g(n))) \implies f(n) = o(g(n))$?

Tags: limits, logarithms

$\log(f(n)) = o(\log(g(n))) \implies f(n) = o(g(n))$?

Is this statement truth or false? And how can it be proven?

I think it is true since the growing differences get even more impact without the log. How to prove it though?

Comment: Try $$f(n)=\frac1n\qquad g(n)=e^{-n}$$

Comment: @S.Peter  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: The example @Did gave here as a comment actually helped me out alot

Comment: @S.Peter And my full explanation wasn't useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\log(f(n)) = o(\log(g(n))) \iff \log(f(n)) = \omega(n)\cdot \log(g(n)) \qquad  \omega(n) \to 0$$

then

$$\implies e^{log(f(n))} = e^{\omega(n)\cdot \log(g(n))}$$

$$\implies f(n) =(g(n))^{ \omega(n)}$$

thus it seems not true in general.

Let try to find a counterexample, that is

- $f(n)=\left(\frac1{n}\right)^{\frac1n}$
- $g(n)=\frac1n$

Comment: So, you post an answer to explain that... you do not have the answer yet, is this correct?

Comment: I’ve shown that from the definition you cannot derive the thesis thus I’ve suggested to prove by a counter example which can be easily constructed from the information I’ve given.

Comment: @gimusi While I don't agree with the way in which this was brought to your attention, I do agree that the post (before the edit) would probably have been better as a comment. I think it is valuable to gain intuition for what such a statement actually implies (and see why it is probably false), but it didn't seem to be a complete answer to me

Comment: @qbert I need to clarify that my mainly intention was to give a way to verify wfat we can obtain by the definition $$\log(f(n)) = o(\log(g(n)))$$ that is $$f(n) =(g(n))^{ \omega(n)}$$ this show that from the definition we cannot derive the thesis and gives all the elements to construct a counter example as I've suggested. That part becomes trivial with the given hints. I would have liked that the asker reached the conclusion by himself but it was not possible for the already mentioned facts. I hope this can clarify why I haven't posted it as a comment. Thanks again your kind comment. Regards